# Combining 2 SQL Tables

Tags: sql, join, rows, multiple-columns

I have the following 2 tables:

```
temp_table w/ columns MAIN_AUTHOR, COLLAB_NAME, COLLAB_ID, RESEARCH_ID
people_person w/ columns id, MAIN_AUTHOR, COLLAB_NAME, COLLAB_ID, RESEARCH_ID
```

temp_table contains data, people_person does not. I want to put all the rows from temp_table into the corresponding columns in people_person. Ive tried different joins but I dont know what kind of join to use/ how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `id` column in `people_person` is auto-increment. So

```
insert into people_person (MAIN_AUTHOR, COLLAB_NAME, COLLAB_ID, RESEARCH_ID)
select MAIN_AUTHOR, COLLAB_NAME, COLLAB_ID, RESEARCH_ID
from temp_table
```

Comment: gucci that did it. thanks i'll verify this as the correct answer. i knew it was super simple, im just a sql newb thanks again bruh